# Does closing a normal bank account affect my credit like closing a credit line?

Tags: credit-score, bank-account, credit-report

I have a checking account that I once opened to divide money into different piles.  I have since stopped doing that and want to close the checking account.  I still have other checking accounts with the bank.

Will that affect my credit score or credit report?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your credit score is based on your use of Debt.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_score_%28United_States%29):

- 35% of your Credit Score is devoted to Debt Payment History.
- 30% of your Credit Score is based on Utilization (basically, the amount of unused credit available).
- 15% of your Credit Score is impacted by your Credit History.
- 10% of your Credit Score is based on Inquiries for new Debt.
- 10% of your Credit Score is determined by Types of Debt.

Opening and closing bank accounts, buying or selling cars without debt, or even buying or selling houses without debt won't affect your credit score.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source?

Comment: I added a link to wikipedia which summarizes the data well.  Their original source is a motley fool article: http://www.fool.com/ccc/check/check02.htm

Comment: Here's a source straight from the horse's mouth: http://www.myfico.com/CreditEducation/WhatsInYourScore.aspx

Comment: I thought "average age of open credit lines" was part of the score. Am I incorrect in thinking that?

Comment: @ShaneWealti You are correct but bank accounts are not open credit lines.

Comment: @AlexB Whoops! You're right. I fail at reading.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [Relevant Article](http://www.bankrate.com/brm/news/DrDon/20061229_credit_report_ChexSystems_a1.asp).  Here's the first paragraph that answers your question:

> The opening and closing of bank (deposit) accounts doesn't affect your credit score. Your credit score is based on your lending relationships and public records, such as bankruptcy filings or court judgments recorded against you.

The rest of the article goes into more detail.

Comment: Proof of why link-only answers get flagged: eight years later, that link (revised May 2014) doesn't mention deposit accounts.